# Nodejs Apple native authentication

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, typescript, authentication

i'm a nodejs backend developer and i have an app with nodejs backend and the client side is ios, swift. I need to to do the feature `sign in with apple`

I figure out there are 2 ways to sign in with apple. One is using restful api, one is sign in with native device.

I know how to do the sign in with apple using restful api, because i worked with `passportjs` and i did the sign in with fb, twitter before. However i don't understand how the `sign in with apple` (the native way) work on the nodejs side.

Here is the article: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/apple-siwa/add-siwa-to-native-app

Comment: Are you using `Firebase` authentication?

Comment: no i don't use `Firebase` for authentication

Comment: I think this will help: https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/sign-in-with-apple-ios-tutorial/

Comment: @Rob after the authentication, do you know how to put the user information into the database ?

Comment: Yes, there is a `delegate` method named `didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization`. It is also mentioned in the `tutorial` once you have fetched the data, then you can call an API, pass the data to the server and then you can get the required data and add it into your database.

Comment: the data return are user (mail,name) and an authenticationCode. Should i just use the user data to POST in the register endpoint, if that the case then what can i do with the authenticationCode ? Is there a way to connect node server to apple developer account ?

Comment: No, I don't think so, I assumed you are an experienced `Node` developer. The `authenticationCode` can be used in other forms. Firebase uses it. Still, that's how you can get the user data, but you can always read the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using regular web app (node), you should use web based flow. Native implementation is not applicable in your case. You can enable Sing In with Apple like any other social login in Auth0. 
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/apple-siwa/add-siwa-to-web-app